Next.js error when loading page ConnectTimeoutError
i got some problem on next.js 15.0.3, node.js 20.15.0 and rocky linux 9.4 (Blue Onyx)
i was trying to navigate to a specific page through the  tag.
but i got error.
[TypeError: fetch failed] {
  cause:  [ConnectTimeoutError: Connect Timeout Error] {
  name: 'ConnectTimeoutError',
  code: 'UND_ERR_CONNECT_TIMEOUT',
  message: 'Connect Timeout Error'
}
}

this component is client compoenet i try to reached.
'use client'

//...
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';
//...
export default function Component() {
    const fileRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
    const [ file, setFile ] = useState<File>();
    //...
    const router = useRouter();
    //...
    const onSave = async () => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        if(file) {
            //...
            formData.append('file', file);
            //...
        } else {
            alert('error');
            return false;
        }
        try {
            const result = await fetch(UPLOAD, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData,
                credentials: 'include',
            }).then(res => res.json());
            if(result.success) {
                router.push(`/path/${result.file_id}`);
            } else {
                alert('error');
            }
        } catch(e) {
            console.error(e);
            alert('error');
        }
    };
    //...
    return <div>
        //...
        <div>file: <input ref={fileRef} type="file" accept="image/*" onChange={onFileChange} /></div>
        <button onClick={onSave}>commit</button>
        //...
    </div>;
}

it load the page very slowly at first time.
but load success then become a normally;
i don't know what is problem.
strangely it works in my computer(next.js 15.0.3, node.js 20.15.0, MacOS).

I wrote more pages and got the following error:
Error: timeout
   at Timeout._onTimeout (/root/server/front/.next/server/chunks/589.js:1:562)
⨯ [Error: An error occurred in the Server Components render. The specific message is omitted in production builds to avoid leaking sensitive details. A digest property is included on this error instance which may provide additional details about the nature of the error.] {
 digest: '2998197250'

and chunks/589.js:1:562 is it
let r = async ({ url: e,
    params: t,
    method: s = "GET",
    body: r }) => {
    let i = new AbortController,
        a = setTimeout(() => {
            throw i.abort(),
            Error("timeout")
        },
            1e4),
        l = await fetch(`${e}?${t}`,
            {
                method: s,
                body: r,
                credentials: "include",
                signal: i.signal
            });
    if (clearTimeout(a), !l.ok) throw Error("fetch failed");
    return l.json()
}

This code appears to have encountered an error while waiting for a response from the server.
But, in reality, the code was running on the backend and no data seemed to be passed to the frontend page.
I don't know how this is possible.
My server has 1 vCPU and 1024MB of RAM.
Is the problem that the server is too slow?
